# Runtime template arguments?

Tags: c++, templates, runtime

I am writing an SI unit class that uses integer template arguments for the dimensions of the type. I am trying to write a power function, but I am running into the issue that the exponent is not necessarily known until runtime and therefore the template arguments are not either.

Some code is omitted in the examples

```cpp
template <int m = 0, int s = 0, int kg = 0, int A = 0, int K = 0, int mol = 0, int cd = 0>
struct Dimension{
  template <typename D, Ratio R> friend class Unit;
  public:
    real value;

    template <int m2, int s2, int kg2, int A2, int K2, int mol2, int cd2>
    constexpr Dimension<m+m2, s+s2, kg+kg2, A+A2, K+K2, mol+mol2, cd+cd2> operator*(Dimension<m2, s2, kg2, A2, K2, mol2, cd2> const & rhs) const {return value*rhs.value;}


   //Power function here
};
```

The multiplication operator works because the result type depends on only template parameters.

None of the following work for the power operator because they all have the template argument depend on a runtime parameter.

```
constexpr auto operator^(int n) const {return Dimension<m*n, s*n, kg*n, A*n, K*n, mol*n, cd*n>{std::pow(value, n)};}

template <int N>
constexpr Dimension<m*N, s*N, kg*N, A*N, K*N, mol*N, cd*N> pow() const {return std::pow(value, N);}

constexpr auto operator^(int n) const {
  if constexpr (n == 0) return Dimension<0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0>{std::pow(value, N)};
  else if constexpr (n == 1) return Dimension<m*N, s*N, kg*N, A*N, K*N, mol*N, cd*N>{std::pow(value, N)};
  else if constexpr (n == 2) return Dimension<m*2, s*2, kg*2, A*2, K*2, mol*2, cd*2>{std::pow(value, N)};
//...
// I can reasonably expect a range smaller than [-10, 10], but theoretically I should be able to have any n
}
```

Sorry if there are minor code mistakes, I have written them directly.

Are there any solutions that don't resort to macros that would let me solve this?

Comment: Function parameters (like `n`) are never constexpr. So `n==0` cannot be used inside `constexpr if`.

Comment: Template parameters must be known at compile time. Perhaps it might be better to re-examine the solution to what you are trying to solve.

Comment: @JasonLiam Yes, that's why I said it wouldn't work

Comment: @Nathan29006781 So you already know the problem that runtime constructs cannot be used in compile time constructs. Don't know what answer you expect here.

Comment: You might want to watch this : [A Physical Units Library For the Next C++ - Mateusz Pusz - CppCon 2020](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7dExYGSOJzo)

Comment: Even if you are able to pass the runtime `n` as a template parameter, the return type of `pow` must also be known at compile time. Since the only way to know the return type is by examine `n` at runtime, it is impossible for `pow` to return different type. Thus you must reexamine the solution and perhaps go for a different route.